# I have successfully queried my database in wordpress/php however it is just showing blank when I try to display the results in a table

Tags: php, html, wordpress

For my website I am making a parametric search to filter through 100's of power supplies, filtering by voltage etc. When I did this locally it worked perfectly however I am struggling when it comes to implementing it to wordpress, here is the code below of my output/the query, I know its a lot of if statements to build up the query, any improvements are greatly appreciated too.

```html
<html>
<?php
$voltage=$_POST["MaxVoltage"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM powersupplies WHERE MaxVoltage >= '".$voltage."'";
    
    if (!empty($_POST["MaxCurrent"])){
        $current=$_POST["MaxCurrent"];
        $currentquery = " AND MaxCurrent >= '".$current."'";
        $sql = $sql.$currentquery;
    } 
    if (!empty($_POST["Make"]) && ($_POST["Make"] != "Any")){
        $make=$_POST["Make"];
        $makequery = " AND Make = '".$make."'";
        $sql = $sql.$makequery;
    } 
    if (!empty($_POST["MaxPower"])){
        $power =$_POST["MaxPower"];
        $powerquery = " AND MaxPower >= '".$power."'";
        $sql = $sql.$powerquery;
    } 
    if (isset($_POST["Programmable"]) && ($_POST["Programmable"] != "Any")){
        $programmable =$_POST["Programmable"];
        $programmablequery = " AND Programmable = '".$programmable."'";
        $sql = $sql.$programmablequery;
    } 
    if (isset($_POST["Negative"])&& ($_POST["Negative"] != "Any")){
        $negative =$_POST["Negative"];
        $negativequery = " AND Negative = '".$negative."'";
        $sql = $sql.$negativequery;
    } 
    if (isset($_POST["Positive"])&& ($_POST["Positive"] != "Any")){
        $positive =$_POST["Positive"];
        $positivequery = " AND Positive = '".$positive."'";
        $sql = $sql.$positivequery;
    } 
    if (isset($_POST["Bipolar"])&& ($_POST["Bipolar"] != "Any")){
        $bipolar =$_POST["Bipolar"];
        $bipolarquery = " AND Bipolar = '".$bipolar."'";
        $sql = $sql.$bipolarquery;
    } 
    if (isset($_POST["Floating"])&& ($_POST["Floating"] != "Any")){
        $floating =$_POST["Floating"];
        $floatingquery = " AND Floating = '".$floating."'";
        $sql = $sql.$floatingquery;
    } 
    if (isset($_POST["Topology"])&& ($_POST["Topology"] != "Any")){
        $topology =$_POST["Topology"];
        $topologyquery = " AND Topology = '".$topology."'";
        $sql = $sql.$topologyquery;
    } 
        $sql = $sql.";";
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
    if ($wpdb->last_error) {
      echo 'You done bad! ' . $wpdb->last_error;
    }
    echo count($result)." results have been found";
    echo "<table>"
    foreach ($result as $row){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["PartNumber"]. 
                "</td><td>" . $row["MaxVoltage"] . 
                "</td><td>" . $row["MaxPower"]. 
                "</td><td>". $row["MaxCurrent"] . 
                "</td><td>". $row["Programmable"] . 
                "</td><td>". $row["Negative"] . 
                "</td><td>". $row["Positive"] . 
                "</td><td>". $row["Bipolar"] . 
                "</td><td>". $row["Floating"] . 
                "</td><td>". $row["Topology"] . 
                "</td><td>". $row["Make"] . 
                "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>"
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share HTML output for this code?

Comment: @AhmedSheashaa thats the issue, the webpage is just blank, at first I just echo'd a long list of partnumbers and that worked fine, but its just gone completely blank when I try do it in a table

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after echo "<table>" above foreach ($result as $row){

Comment: @AhmedSheashaa its always the simple things... Thank you very much :D